# how to deploy war compiled in java 1.8 in jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have upgraded my web application which was earlier in java 1.7 to java 1.8. However when I try to deploy its war in jboss 7 ,
I get following exception.

```
[jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

18:49:41,659 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/nlp_Server]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
18:49:41,659 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Error listenerStart
18:49:41,659 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Context [/nlp_Server] startup failed due to previous errors
18:49:41,675 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

18:49:41,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:49:41,675 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4540ms - Started 213 of 294 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 78 services are passive or on-demand)
18:49:41,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "nlp_Server.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
18:49:41,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "MemberManagement.war" was rolled back with no failure message
18:49:41,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MemberManagement.war in 48ms
18:49:42,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment nlp_Server.war in 128ms
18:49:42,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

18:49:42,018 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
18:49:42,018 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./nlp_Server: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
18:49:44,732 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
```

The same war is getting successfully deployed in tomcat.

Comment: Please format your question, it is a pain to the eye because the stacktrace is just an assortment of words.  And you could rename it: you are not trying to deploy but you are seeking information how to solve a certain exception

Comment: what is nlp_Server in your jboss, could you please post your standalone.configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Jboss seems to run on JDK 7.

from your log:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
```

but you compile your source using JDK 8, so JDK7 cannot run the compiled code from JDK 8.

Please add source and target when you compile the source code.

e.g. javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7

Comment: @ diufanman: your solution was helpful however i found my answer. i have posted it below. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ParthaBisoi this is the correct answer to your question, changing the application server is not. You can keep using the latest jdk while setting the proper compilation level (in eclipse for example java->compiler->compiler compliance level)

Comment: @ Paizo: agreed with your point and marking the same as answered

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. jboss 7 do not support jdk 1.8 as such. I have downloaded jboss-eap-6.4.0 which have jdk 1.8 support. 
My application now works fine.